# Customize Payment form using authorize.net gateway

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am integrating authorize.net payment gateway with my ecommerce website. I am able to integrate the payment form using SIM method.

However, the problem is with the payment form itself. There are too many input fields which needs to be entered. Is it possible to customize it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log into the account control panel you can control what fields are captured from there.

1. Log in to your Authorize.Net account (either test or live)
2. Click on the "Account" tab at the top of the page
3. In the first section, "Transaction Format Settings", under the "Transaction Submission Settings" sub-section, click on "Payment Form".
4. On the page that displays, click on "Form Fields"